# HTML5 audio no method play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, media-player

My markup

And this JQuery code

keeps on giving me error each time I press play

```
<div class = "container">
    <legend><strong>Zedd - Spectrum</legend></h4>
    <div class = "art-item"><img src="uploads/arts/default.jpg"></div>
        <audio class = "audio-player" src = "uploads/tracks/02 So Far.mp3">
        </audio>

            <div class = "playerContainer">

                <ul id =  "playerControls" >
                    <li class = "play-bt"></li>
                    <li class = "pause-bt"></li>
                    <li><div class ="progressContainer"><!-- Progess bars container //-->
                        <div class ="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <span class ="timecode">0:00</span>
            </div>
</div>


<div class = "container">
    <legend><strong>Zedd - Spectrum</legend></h4>
    <div class = "art-item"><img src="uploads/arts/default.jpg"></div>
        <audio class = "audio-player" src = "uploads/tracks/track3.mp3">
        </audio>

            <div class = "playerContainer">

                <ul id =  "playerControls" >
                    <li class = "play-bt"></li>
                    <li class = "pause-bt"></li>
                    <li><div class ="progressContainer"><!-- Progess bars container //-->
                        <div class ="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <span class ="timecode">0:00</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Each time I click the play-bt it keeps on giving me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'play'
```

aren't audio tags has a play method?

Comment: Just to add on what others have said,try to serve the html page containing the media player from a webserver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), not a native [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAudioElement), so you need to [unwrap the value](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returned by `.find()`:

```
$artItem.find('audio')[0].play();
// or
$artItem.find('audio').get(0).play();
```

Comment: what about if I have 2 audio players? but its in a different container?

Comment: @user962206 I don't quite follow. Perhaps you could edit your question to show the markup you're actually using.

Comment: @user962206 Consider reading something about [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: @user962206 meaning if you took the time to learn Javascript before smashing stuff together with a Javascript toolkit you might have caught this very simple error from the beginning and your second question would be moot. Not trying to be harsh, just trying to make it obvious that you need to back up and take a few days to learn JS.

Comment: @rlemon I thought that it would initially return the DOM itself. but I assumed wrong.

Comment: @user962206 that's what RTFDing is for.

Comment: Well I was caught off guarded. but Thanks anyway! :) Now I understood. Thanks guys. although rlemon was kinda offensive

Comment: Offensive === the truth. Really, if you want to learn ping me and i'll give you a good number of free resources. I may sometimes be harsh, but it is to only point out the fallacy in trying to use a toolkit for a language you do not understand the agnostics of.

Answer (score 1):

You access the jquery, not the plain dom tag here
So try:

```
$artItem.find("audio")[0].play()
```